# How to capture a form's exceptions in the dpr

Tags: delphi

I need to capture all non-unit initialization exceptions in a Delphi 7 program so I can write the exception to a file, and perhaps show the user a message.

Reading up on this, I thought that a global exception handler would be cumbersome and that all I would need is to capture all exceptions at the DPR level.  However, I can't get the code below to ever get to the ShowMessage in the dpr.

Why does the Raise Exception below actually result in an exception displayed on the screen rather than bouncing out to the .dpr's except clause? Maybe a global exception handler would be a better approach?

Shouldn't the code immediately below in the dpr capture all exceptions in a form?

In DPR:

```
begin
  Application.Initialize;
  try
    Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
    Application.Run;
  except
    On E: Exception do
      ShowMessage('In dpr except. Exception is: ' + E.Message);
  end;    
end.
```

In Form:

```
Function TForm1.DoSomething( out aErrm: String):boolean; // force a failure for testing
begin
  Result := FALSE;
  aErrm := 'Failed in DoSomething';
end;

procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject); 
begin
  try
    fOk := DoSomething(fErrm);
  except
    fOk := FALSE;
    Errm := 'Unexpected exception'
  end;

  if (NOT fOk) then
    Raise Exception.Create(Errm) // why does this pop-up an exception when the DPR has an except around this code?
  else
    PostMessage(Handle, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0); // self-closing form
end;  { FormActivate }
```

Comment: I read you Q twice and failed to understand why you are dissatisfied with exception handling provided by `TApplication` class and feel the urge to to make a your own.

Comment: You should not have accepted my answer, @PeterVonča hit the point.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The main message loop in [TApplication.Run](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/FMX.Forms.TApplication.Run) wraps and handles all Messages in an exception block, which as a result catches all exceptions thus rendering your primary exception block in the DPR completely useless.

If you want to capture & handle Application exceptions then use [TApplication.OnException](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/Vcl.Forms.TApplication.OnException).

Comment: `CreateForm` is guarded too, so all unit exceptions are catchable and recoverable, with an exception of exceptions (EPun, sorry) thrown outside Application instance life-time (eg: unit initialization and finalization)

Comment: @user539484 that may be so , but if you take the example that was given with the Raise exception being triggered in the Form.Show, then the last in line exception block to intercept the exception before the DPR one lies in the Run method.